# select tag headerKey with empty value

Tags: jsp, struts2

I would like to know if it's possible to set **`headerKey`** to be empty so it would look like following in DOM:

```
<option value="">All</option>
```

**My code:**

```
<s:select name="..." headerKey="" headerValue="All" list="#{...}" id="..." style="..." tabindex="1" />
```

I'm aware that in the Struts2 document, it says `headerKey` should **NOT** be empty, but I would like to know if there's a way to get around it.

Comment: This issue might've become irrelevant since I was using javaTemplate plugin to override struts2 tags which caused the issue. Without javaTemplate plugin, leaving headerKey empty would make option value  look like exactly what I desired in DOM.

Answer (score 0):

What I have typically done in the past is when I generate the map of key/value pairs that the select is based from in my action class, I use a `LinkedHashMap` and place the `All` option with an empty key as the first map entry.

```
public class UnitOfMeasureSelectAction extends DefaultAction {
  private Map<String, String> unitsOfMeasure;
  @Override
  public String execute() throws Exception {
    unitsOfMeasure = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    unitsOfMeasure.put( StringUtils.EMPTY, getText( "lov.common.all" ) );
    unitsOfMeasure.putAll( unitsOfMeasureService.getUomMap() );
    return SUCCESS;
  }
  public Map<String, String> getUnitsOfMeasure() {
    return unitsOfMeasure
  }
}
```